# How to "Update Frame" in Xcode 8

Tags: xcode

I have updated to Xcode 8.1. Usually when I've miss-edited a Frame that has Auto Constraints, I've pressed on "Update Frame" to revoke my changes. But this option seemed to be gone since the new Update.

[image]

How do I update the Frame back to the Auto Constraints value now? Or is the "Update Frame" Option somewhere else now? Help is very appreciated.

Comment: Cmd + Alt + ;  shortcut

Comment: thanks for the shortcut

Answer (score 32, accepted):

In Xcode 8, storyboards have been greatly improved to make what you see on the screen exactly the same as what you would see on the device when you run your app. And even though frames might update as you move things, **there's a new handy standalone button** to the leftmost side of the button you have selected in your question (it looks like a refresh button).

Theres's a few more options as well:

- You can use the keyboard shortcut: <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Opt</kbd> + <kbd>=</kbd>
- You can also look for "Update Frames", by going to the toolbar and selecting `Editor -> Resolve Auto Layout Issues -> Update Frames`.

Answer (score 24):

> There is a new Update Frames button at the bottom of the canvas. Click the button to update the frames of the selected objects and their children on the Interface Builder canvas.

[image]

**Source** - https://developerinsider.co/whats-new-in-xcode-8/

Comment: This is a shortcut better than the selected answer. thank and +1

Answer (score 7):

Near the Stack button, there is a new "Update frame" button, its just left to the stack button (you can see it in your screenshot)